# String definition error in Python due to apostrophe number

Tags: python, string, apostrophe

In codefight, there is a question:

> Which of the given string definitions are incorrect?
>
> 1. s = 'abacaba'
> 2. s = "abacaba"
> 3. s = ' 'abacaba' '
> 4. s = ""abacaba""
> 5. s = ' ' 'abacaba' ' '
> 6. s = """abacaba"""

The definitions in 3 and 4 are wrong.

My question is if 3 and 4 are wrong way of defining string, shouldn't 5 and 6 be wrong for similar reasoning?

Comment: no. threee double/single quotations are valid. have a look up to string documentation.

Comment: triple quotes are used for `docstrings` in python just like javadoc.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: Look here at [PEP257: What is docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) ?

Comment: @DineshKumar And multi-line string literals

Comment: @abccd you are right. I missed tht :)

Comment: "*for similar reasoning*" - well, what reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer your question

When you use 3 single quotes or 3 double quotes you can have a string that spans `multiple lines`. That is the reason why you have it for your doc strings. Please see the below example.

```
>>> s ="""Hello
... whats going on
... thats it"""
>>> s
'Hello\nwhats going on\nthats it'
>>>
```

However when 2 single quotes(`''`) are used or 2 double quotes (`""`) are used and if you need the string to be encapsulated inside they quotation it should be like below.

```
"'Hello'" or '\'Hello\''
'"Hello'" or "\"Hello\""
```

If you don't do this python interpreter expects a value for 'Hello' instead of considering it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

3 and 4 are wrong because '' is empty string and abacaba will be treated as variable so you need to write it as `'' + str(abacaba) + ''` which will concate your string and also you have to assign value of abacaba before use.

Now your answer when you use `"""abacaba"""` python will find three different strings `""`, `"abacaba"` and `""` and your result will be `'abacaba'`.
this happen because you need `+` sign to concate string stored in variable but for string like `"abc"` and `"xyz"` if you write `s="abc" "xyz"` or `s="abc""xyz"` you will get result `'abcxyz'`

Here is few examples for you:

```
>>> s="abc" "xyz"
>>> s
'abcxyz'
>>> s="1""abc""1"
>>> s
'1abc1'
>>> s="1"  "abc"  "1"
>>> s
'1abc1'
>>> s="1"abc"1"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> abc="2"
>>> s="1"abc"1"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> s="1"+abc+"1"
>>> s
'121'
>>> s=r"""abc"""  # raw string which will treat all content/special character between "" as your string
>>> s
'abc'
```

Answer (score -1):

Triple quotes are used most commonly for method descriptions in python.  These method descriptions are called `docstrings` and are represented as multi-line string literals `""" """`

Here is a sample in python.

```
def testdocstring():
    """
    this is a test docstring method
    :return: None
    """
    pass

print testdocstring.__doc__
```

The output of this `print` statement will be:

```
  this is a test docstring method
  :return: None
```

**EDIT :** As @Varad and @abccd have mentioned, it is also used for multi- line string literals.

Comment: It's not really to do with javadoc. Docstrings are a specific application of multiline string literals, not the other way around.

Comment: @PeterWood Hmmm..maybe..but what I meant was where it is commonly used.

Comment: *"Why do we need them? The same reason we need javadoc"* is a really wrong explanation of why we need multi-line string literals.

Comment: Agreed. Updated my answer.